# How to prevent FOUT with dotdotdot?

Tags: jquery, dotdotdot

I am using the [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) plugin to cut off texts.

The problem is that on slower devices I get a flash of unformatted output - it loads the whole text and only after a moment dotdotdot fires and cuts it off. If you want to see an example, just open [their site](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) on a something like a smartphone - at the first example blocks you will see both blocks get the full text and only after a moment is the right block cut off.

Is there anything I can do to prevent this?

Comment: you need to make sure that the plugin loads as fast as possible, preferably right after the html load

Comment: and why an earth does this plugin need jquery?

Comment: @madalinivascu i believe it's jist because the author wanted to write it in jquery. Do you know a better plugin?

Comment: yes its called javascript  :))

Comment: @madalinivascu I mean can you recommend an alternative plugin that cuts off overflowing text and inserts an ellipsis? Other than the "code the functionality yourself" plugin? :D

Comment: man this will take like less then 10 lines of code, i don't know any other plugin sory :(

Comment: @madalinivascu Actually it's a lot more as you have to a lot of concerns. Like watch out from breaking tags or leaving them open...